# How to solve the error for File object's parameter in Android Studio IDE

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the list of files and my code as follows.

```
public static void deleteWithExtension(Context mContext, String extension) {
    File dir = new File(mContext.getFilesDir());
        final String[] theFiles = dir.list();
        for (final String file : theFiles) {
            //do something here....
            int aa=9;
            //The code never goes into here, because theFiles Array is always null
        }
    }
}
```

But the IDE shows red underline at line 2 -> `File dir = new File(**mContext.getFilesDir()**);`

It is underlining the part -> `mContext.getFilesDir()` of that line.

When I move my mouse onto that red-underline part I get an explanation saying "Cannot resolve constructor `File(java.io.File)`"

Just to inform, `import java.io.File;` is exist at the top my code.

Why is that and how to solve.

Comment: File dir = mContext.getFilesDir();

Answer (score 0):

`getFilesDir()` already returns a `File` object, so you can remove the `new File` part entirely and just use the returned `File` directly:

```
File dir = mContext.getFilesDir();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed. The red problem gone away. But now I have a new problem. The code never goes into for-loop because the theFiles[] array is null, . I am sure that there are many files under mContext.getFilesDir

Comment: What makes you think that? `getFilesDir()` is a directory unique to your app that no other app has access to. If you haven't written any files into that directory, then it would be expected that there's nothing there.

Comment: In my app, I am creating many files for temporary purposes. All of them has same extension, say ".xxx". I just wanted to add a method in my main_activity to delete all these *.xxx files when the app started for a clean start.